# Load the same scene objects in Unity, for players using Google Play Games

Tags: unity-game-engine, real-time, google-play-games

I currently need to show the same scene for both players; hence, having same objects, objects being destroyed when clicked by a player in real time and so on.

I have successfully setup a room for 2 players. But instead of having the same scene loaded, the multiplayer scene is being loaded as new for both players (Since the load scene method is being called from two different scenes).

TLDR; How can I instantiate the same scene, for both players?

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't the way multiplayer works. Each client will run their own instance of the scene. If an object is created or destroyed within the scene, you need to create an RPC call that tells every client to Instantiate() the same object at the same position (preferably with the same rotation).

Comment: Hello @BrandonMiller, thanks for your quick reply!

Is it possible to initiate an RPC call, with Google Play Services, or do I need to make use of a service like Photon? 

Thanks

Comment: I've never used Google Play Services but they should offer some sort of "Messaging" or "Broadcast" function that allows you to transmit data to all connected clients. Look through the API and the guides for something to that effect.

Comment: @BrandonMiller Thanks, will do! :)